# Define the parent of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to define a structure when accessing variables. Let's say I have a `document` and a `body`. To access this in JavaScript, I use `document` and `document.body`
That sounds great to me, so I'd like to **apply it** to my whole site.

But when I try to define a nested object, I can define values inside but not the object itself.

I can do this:

```js
var main = {
  nav: {
    button: document.querySelectorAll('main nav button')
  }
}
```

and access it like this:

```
main.nav.button[0].innerHTML = 'Test'
```

But what about `main` and `nav`?! I **can't define** them...
Is there any solution for doing something like this

```
var main = 'something' {
  nav: 'something else' {
    button: 'still something else'
  }
}
```

in JavaScript? Or how did JavaScript defined `document` **and** `document.body` at the same time?

### Updates

- **9/30/2020** | Question clarified

Comment: your first example works perfectly well for me on chrome, 
var main = {
  nav: {
    button: document.querySelectorAll('button')
  }
}
main.nav.button[8].innerText  = '123'

Comment: I can confirm that it works for me on the Firefox console as well. It could be that the nodes aren't ready yet by the time you call main.nav.button[0].innerHTML

Comment: NB: Don't try to make `document.body.main` work. You should leave the DOM for DOM elements, not for your own variables. Indeed, creating your own `main` nested object is fine, and works.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically there already.  Define main as an empty object..

`document.body.main = {};`

and then on that

`document.body.main.nav = {};`

Just always remember to assign an empty object `{}` before trying to dot down into it.

Comment: I thought that I was clear. I'm trying put into `main` some variable, **but also** define itself. Ex: `main = 'something'` and `main.nav = 'something else'`

Answer (score 0):

With [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object you can customize and implement all sorts of crazy ideas.

```js
const handler = {
  get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
    if (Reflect.has(target, prop)) {
      return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    } else {
      const nextTarget = target.querySelector('scope > ' + prop);
      if (!nextTarget) return undefined;
      return new Proxy(nextTarget, handler)
    }
  }
};

const myDocument = new Proxy(document, handler)
```